# No se encontró OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, oledb

Hola de nuevo yo pero con otro inconveniente

Hice un proyecto de prueba para conectar y guardar mis datos en una base de datos access y todo funciono correctamente, entonces tome el código que hice y lo coloque en el proyecto en el que estoy trabajando pero OleDbConnection que es parte de mi código me dice que no lo encuentra y me marca error
tambien agregue las mismas librerias
todo lo que use en el código de prueba lo puse aquí, y no se que paso
como se muestra en la imagen que esta mal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya agregastes la referencia al proyecto?, en este caso system.data.dll

Comment: @HeynerMartinez intente agregarla pero no me lo permite, me marca error., la que estoy usando es system.data.oledb

Comment: estoy usando estos: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;

Comment: que error marca?

Comment: @gbianchi el que muestra la imagen que puse, me dice que no se encuentra, cuando ya tengo  las librerias

Comment: mostra el error completo.. lo que estas mostrando es la linea donde esta el error, y tu traduccion del error. Cual es el error completo?

Comment: Y tanto error como codigo, deben ir como texto, siempre...

Comment: @gbianchi me muestra lo siguiente:    CS1069: No se encuentra el nombre tipo 'oledbconnection' en el espacio de nombres 'system.data.oledb'.... voy a la pagina donde me muestra lo que quieren decir los errores pero no se encuentra disponible

Comment: instalaste la dependencia??? agregaste el using?

Comment: sii, hice todo eso, ademas en el que hice de prueba todo funciono correctamente

Comment: Ya pude solucionar el problema, de algun modo funciono, gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Bien, si tenés la versión 2022 posiblemente tengas que descargar un paquete, vas al explorador de soluciones, hacés clic derecho sobre el nombre del proyecto/administrador de paquetes nuGet/examinar/ y buscás `System.Data.OleDb`, y descargás la versión más estable que dice .Net